# Wireless cannot ping router after five minutes inactivity 

Tags: 11.04, wireless, dns, modprobe

As the title says when I don't use the net for ~5 mins I cannot resolve hostnames, either via browser or using apt-cache or similiar. Wget will return the first line and just timeout. I need to `modprobe -r` and `modprobe r8192e_pci` to get things working again.

I've blacklisted `r8192se_pci` using the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file. Running 11.04 clean install on a samsung n-130 netbook and connecting to a WPA2 router.

Anyone else experienced this issue? Any suggested fixes?

**UPDATE** Still no joy, although I can confirm that when the issue happens it's not just the DNS that goes, I cannot ping beyond the laptop.

Comment: maybe this thread will help: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1321340

Comment: Thanks I've blacklisted the ethernet connection and so far so good, going to leave the netbook for 15 mins and see if it drops again. Fingers crossed :)

Comment: No luck, still dropping

Answer (score 1):

As was stated in a comment:

> Got it up and running at last, I had configured it correctly before but should have just ignored the ifdown errors and ifup'd right after. Going leaving the netbook for 20 mins now and we'll see what's what.

Answer (score 0):

(This isn't really an answer but I don't yet have a sufficiently high reputation to comment).

Assuming you're running Network Manager, have you tried disabling it temporarily (("sudo service network-manager stop" or similar). I've encountered situations in the past where Network Manger periodically nuked my wired network interface for no apparent reason.

Comment: Well stopping network manager gave me pretty much the exact same symptoms so I think we're on the right track :) How do I go about configuring the wireless to connect while network manager is stopped? I seem to recall something about an /etc/network or something similiar on fedora?

Comment: Is your wireless connection truly down or is it simply that stopping network manager left your wireless network interface without an IP address? I suspect the latter in which case "dhclient wlan0" (or whatever the name of your wireless network interface is) should have you back in business.

Comment: ...otherwise, you'll need to use "iwconfig" to connect to your router. See "man iwconfig" and "man wireless".

Comment: dhclient wlan0 didn't work, just stayed at a blinking cursor for 3 mins until I hit ctrl + c. I used iwconfig to set the correct essid(it had defaulted to some funky essid with a lot of \ in it) but I was unable to set the wpa key, going to have to take a proper look at wpa_supplicant I think. I'm off to bed for the night will have another crack at it tomorrow. Thanks for all the help so far, really appreciate it. I'd rate your comments and answers but not enough rep at the moment :(

Comment: Got it up and running at last, I had configured it correctly before but should have just ignored the ifdown errors and ifup'd right after. Going leaving the netbook for 20 mins now and we'll see what's what.

Comment: Still going down, however ifdown wlan0 followed by ifup wlan0 restores connection instantly. Seems to be a power saving option or something, any suggestions on forcing it to stay up?

Comment: No clue I'm afraid. One thought: have you checked /var/log/syslog and friends to see if there are any interesting/relevant messages around the time your wireless connection drops out?